# Why doesn't print force entire lazy IO value?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes, http-conduit, lazy-io

I'm using [http-client](https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client) tutorial to get response body using TLS connection. Since I can observe that `print` is called by `withResponse`, why doesn't `print` force entire response to the output in the following fragment?

```
withResponse request manager $ \response -> do
    putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++
    body <- (responseBody response)
    print body
```

I need to write this instead:

```
response <- httpLbs request manager

putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++
           show (statusCode $ responseStatus response)
print $ responseBody response
```

Body I want to print is a lazy ByteString. I'm still not sure whether I should expect `print` to print the entire value.

```
instance Show ByteString where
    showsPrec p ps r = showsPrec p (unpackChars ps) r
```

Comment: Print is just `putStrLn` and `show`.  So what you should probably be asking is "why doesn't 'Show' fully evaluate the value?".  I suspect the answer will be obvious once you look at the Show instance for whatever the body type is.  Also notice the only portion of the response that would be forced is the body, not the status or other fields.

Comment: Re-reading your question, it appears you want one value, `response`, to be evaluated when calling print on another value, `body`.  Is that the case?  If so, why would you expect that behavior in the first place?

Comment: What happened to the `show (statusCode) ...` line in the first snippet?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with laziness, it's the difference between the `Response L.ByteString` you get in the "simple" case, and the `Response BodyReader` you get in the tls case. A `BodyReader` cant be printed directly since it's an IO action. But it's an action that can be repeated, yielding a new chunk each time. It follows the familiar protocol that when it is  'done' when it gets an empty bytestring.  In your tls case, you are just printing the first chunk, but you need a loop to print the results as they come, til you hit an empty chunk.

Comment: sevo, look at the difference between `bip` and `bop` here http://lpaste.net/8526468113670078464 You wrote `bip` which only fetches once, so to speak, and prints one nice-sized chunk - in this case the first couple chapters of the king james bible. But you want `bop` which prints chunks until it hits an empty chunk, and thus prints the whole translation.

Comment: @Michael Comments are an impoverished space, which probably explains why you put your code in an lpaste instead of including it inline. Why not turn it into an answer, where you have enough space to include all the details without linking elsewhere? =)

Comment: @Michael Please make this an answer. I was hasty and not aware that "body" means "body chunk of arbitrary size" in this API. I'm still confused about the types and names in this API but you helped me to realize my mistake.

Comment: @DanielWagner Okay I wrote a long version fwiw.

Comment: The first example has a syntax error (trailing `++`). Please fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with laziness, but with the difference between the `Response L.ByteString` you get with the Simple module, and the `Response BodyReader` you get with the TLS module.

You noticed that a `BodyReader` is an `IO ByteString`. But in particular it is an action that can be repeated, each time with the *next* chunk of bytes. It follows the protocol that it never sends a null bytestring except when it's at the end of file. (`BodyReader` might have been called `ChunkGetter`). `bip` below is like what you wrote: after extracting the `BodyReader`/`IO ByteString` from the `Response`, it performs it to get the first chunk, and prints it. But doesn't repeat the action to get more - so in this case we just see the first couple chapters of Genesis. What you need is a loop to exhaust the chunks, as in `bop` below, which causes the whole King James Bible to spill into the console.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} 
import Network.HTTP.Client
import Network.HTTP.Client.TLS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

main = bip
-- main = bop

bip = do 
  manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
  request <- parseRequest "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelt/kjv/master/kjv.txt"
  withResponse request manager $ \response -> do
      putStrLn "The status code was: "  
      print (responseStatus response)
      chunk  <- responseBody response
      B.putStrLn chunk

bop = do 
  manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
  request <- parseRequest "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelt/kjv/master/kjv.txt"
  withResponse request manager $ \response -> do
      putStrLn "The status code was: " 
      print (responseStatus response)
      let loop = do 
            chunk <- responseBody response
            if B.null chunk 
              then return () 
              else B.putStr chunk  >> loop 
      loop
```

The loop keeps going back to get more chunks until it gets an empty string, which represents eof, so in the terminal it prints through to the end of the Apocalypse.

This is behavior is straightforward but slightly technical. You can only work with a `BodyReader` by hand-written recursion. But the purpose of the `http-client` library is to make things like `http-conduit` possible. There the result of [`withResponse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.2.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html#v:withResponse) has the type `Response (ConduitM i ByteString m ())`. `ConduitM i ByteString m ()` is how conduit types of a byte stream; this byte stream would contain the whole file.

In the original form of the `http-client`/`http-conduit` material, the `Response` contained a conduit like this; the `BodyReader` part was later factored out into `http-client` so it could be used by different streaming libraries like `pipes`.

So to take a simple example, in the corresponding http material for the [`streaming`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) and [`streaming-bytestring`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring) libraries, [`withHTTP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-utils-0.1.4.3/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming-HTTP.html#v:withHTTP) gives you a response of type `Response (ByteString IO ())`.  `ByteString IO ()` is the type of a stream of bytes arising in IO, as its name suggests; `ByteString Identity ()` would be the equivalent of a lazy bytestring (effectively a pure list of chunks.)  The `ByteString IO ()` will in this case represent the whole bytestream down to the Apocalypse. So with the imports

```
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.HTTP as Bytes -- streaming-utils
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8 as Bytes -- streaming-bytestring
```

the program is identical to a lazy bytestring program:

```
bap = do 
    manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
    request <- parseRequest "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelt/kjv/master/kjv.txt"
    Bytes.withHTTP request manager $ \response -> do 
        putStrLn "The status code was: "
        print (responseStatus response)
        Bytes.putStrLn $ responseBody response
```

Indeed it is slightly simpler, since you don't have "extract the bytes from IO`:

```
        lazy_bytes <- responseStatus response
        Lazy.putStrLn lazy_bytes
```

but just write

```
        Bytes.putStrLn $ responseBody response
```

you just "print" them directly.  If you want to view just a bit from the middle of the KJV, you can instead do what you would with a lazy bytestring, and end with:

```
        Bytes.putStrLn $ Bytes.take 1000 $ Bytes.drop 50000 $ responseBody response
```

Then you will see something about Abraham.

The `withHTTP` for `streaming-bytestring` just hides the recursive looping that we needed to use the `BodyReader` material from `http-client` directly. It's the same e.g. with the `withHTTP` you find in [`pipes-http`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-http), which represents a stream of bytestring chunks as `Producer ByteString IO ()`, and the same with `http-conduit`. In all of these cases, once you have your hands on the byte stream you handle it in the ways typical of the streaming IO framework without handwritten recursion. All of them use the `BodyReader` from `http-client` to do this, and this was the main purpose of the library.